# deserializing a JSON file with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I develop an Android application and I have to deserialize a JSON file.
I have these classes:

```
public class Medicine {

    @SerializedName("substanta_activa")
    private List<String> active_substance;
    @SerializedName("produse")
    private List<Product> product;
    @SerializedName("dozaj")
    private Dosage dosage;
    @SerializedName("mentiuni")
    private List<String> notes;
    @SerializedName("cuvinte_cheie")
    private List<String> keyword;

    /* + getters and setters */
}
```

---

```
public class Product {

    @SerializedName("denumire_comerciala")
    private String productName;

    @SerializedName("forme_de_prezentare")
    private List<String> form;

    /* + getters and setters */
}
```

---

```
public class Dosage {
    @SerializedName("nounascuti")
    private String newborn;

    @SerializedName("copii")
    private String child;

    @SerializedName("adulti")
    private String adult;

    /* + getters and setters */
}
```

And I have the following JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "substanta_activa": [
            "trimebutinum"
        ],
        "produse": [
            {
                "denumire_comerciala": "Debridat",
                "forme_de_prezentare": [
                    "susp. buvabilă",
                    "susp. 24mg/5ml în flac 250ml",
                    "compr 100mg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "denumire_comerciala": "Ibutin",
                "forme_de_prezentare": [
                    "compr 300mg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "denumire_comerciala": "Trimebutin",
                "forme_de_prezentare": [
                    "compr 100mg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "denumire_comerciala": "Colperin",
                "forme_de_prezentare": [
                    "compr 100mg"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "dozaj": {
            "nounascuti": "1ml/kg/zi div 3,",
            "copii": "1ml/kg/zi div 3, peste 5 ani 3x10ml",
            "adulti": "3x1-2 compr/zi, 1x300mg/zi sau 3x1-2 lingură/zi"
        },
        "mentiuni": [
            "se poate administra de la naștere",
            "se poate administra amestecat cu apă, lapte",
            "10ml conține 6g zahăr"
        ],
        "cuvinte_cheie": [
            "gastro",
            "colică",
            "dureri abdominale funcționale",
            "constipație"
        ]
    },
    {
        "substanta_activa": [
            "benzydaminum"
        ],
        "produse": [
            {
                "denumire_comerciala": "Tantum Verde comprimate",
                "forme_de_prezentare": [
                    "pastile pt supt 3mg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "denumire_comerciala": "Tantum Verde spray",
                "forme_de_prezentare": [
                    "spray bucofaringian 0,15%, 0,3%"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "dozaj": {
            "nounascuti": "contraindicat",
            "copii": "2-6 ani: 2-6x1 puf/4kg; >6 sni: 2-6x 4doze sau 3x1 pastila/zi",
            "adulti": "2-6x 4puf sau 3x1 pastila/zi"
        },
        "mentiuni": [
            "se admin. max. 7 zile"
        ],
        "cuvinte_cheie": [
            "antiseptic, anestezic, antiinflamator, oral, OTC"
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried several ways, with GSON and without it as well but with no success. Thank you for your help in advance.

**EDIT**

A little bit more detail:
I have a MainPageActivity, where I initialize an Inputstream, set a path and call my deserialize method from JSONParser class:

```
InputStream is = null;
String internalStoragePath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File fileToInternalStorage = new File(internalStoragePath + "/medicinelist.json");
try {
     is = new FileInputStream(fileToInternalStorage);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
if (is == null) {
     is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gyogyszerek);
}
jsonParser = new JSONParser();
try {
     medicines = jsonParser.readJsonStream(getApplicationContext(), is);
     //medicines = jsonParser.jsonDeserializer(getApplicationContext(), is);
     is.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In my JSONParser class, as I have mentioned I have tried several ways to deserialize the JSON input.
Here is the "traditional" way, with Android's built-in JsonReader class (sorry, a little bit long):

```
public ArrayList readJsonStream(Context applicationContext, InputStream in) throws IOException {
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

    try {
        return readMedicineArray(reader);
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}


public ArrayList readMedicineArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    ArrayList medicines = new ArrayList();
    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        medicines.add(readMedicine(reader));
    }
    reader.endArray();
    return medicines;
}

public Medicine readMedicine(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    List active_substance = null;
    List product = null;
    Dosage dosage = null;
    List notes = null;
    List keyword = null;

    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();

        if (name.equals("substanta_activa")) {
            active_substance = readActiveSubstanceArray(reader);
        } else if (name.equals("produse")) {
            product = readProductArray(reader);
        } else if (name.equals("dozaj")) {
            dosage = readDosage (reader);
        } else if (name.equals("mentiuni") && reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) { 
            notes= readNotesArray(reader);
        } else if (name.equals("cuvinte_cheie") && reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {
            keyword = readKeywordArray(reader);
        } else {
            reader.skipValue();
        }
    }
    reader.endObject();
    return new Medicine(active_substance, product, dosage, notes, keyword);
}

public List readActiveSubstanceArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    List active_substance = new ArrayList();

    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        active_substance.add(reader.nextString());
    }
    reader.endArray();
    return active_substance;
}

public List readProductArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    List product = new ArrayList();

    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        product.add(readProduct(reader));
    }
    reader.endArray();
    return product;
}

public Product readProduct(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    String productName = null;
    List form = null;

    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("denumire_comerciala")) {
            productName = reader.nextString();
        } else if (name.equals("forme_de_prezentare")) {
            form = readFormArray(reader);
        } else {
            reader.skipValue();
        }
    }
    reader.endObject();
    return new Product(productName, form);
}

public List readFormArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    List form = new ArrayList();

    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        form.add(reader.nextString());
    }
    reader.endArray();
    return form;
}

public Dosage readDosage(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    String newborn= null;
    String child= null;
    String adult= null;

    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("nounascuti")) {
            newborn= reader.nextString();
        } else if (name.equals("copii")) {
            child= reader.nextString();
        } else if (name.equals("adulti")) {
            adult= reader.nextString();
        } else {
            reader.skipValue();
        }
    }
    reader.endObject();
    return new Dosage(newborn, child, adult);
}

public List readNotesArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    List notes= new ArrayList();

    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        notes.add(reader.nextString());
    }
    reader.endArray();
    return notes;
}

public List readKeywordArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    List keyword= new ArrayList();

    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        keyword.add(reader.nextString());
    }
    reader.endArray();
    return keyword;
}
```

And here is the other way with GSON library:

```
public ArrayList<Medicine> jsonDeserializer(Context contexts, InputStream in) throws IOException {
      Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

      ArrayList medicinesList = new ArrayList();
      final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
      final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

      Medicine[] medicinesArray = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Medicine[].class);
      for(int i = 0; i < medicinesArray.length; ++i){
          medicinesList.add(medicinesArray[i]);
      }

      return medicinesList;
}
```

None of them works, but I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: What do mean by *"no success"*? What is happening? Where is your deserialization code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//try this

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Medicine>>() {}.getType();
    List<Medicine> medList = gson.fromJson(<YOUR JSON STRING>, listType);
```

Comment: Where does the jsonObject come from? Is it a GSON type variable?

Comment: Modified the answer please try this.

Comment: Just tried this with the data you pasted above, its parsing properly. Can you please explain what is not working.

Comment: It runs, but if I check the size of medList, it's 11, although my JSON file contains only 10 objects. And from MainPageActivity when I try to iterate it, for example get the active_substance list from it, it throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you please post your data here.

Comment: ArrayList<Medicine> medicines = jsonParser.jsonDeserializer(getApplicationContext(), getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.medicinejson)); This runs, but when I try to access the objects' fields, it throws the error.

Comment: Can you please post the content of R.raw.medicinejson

Comment: You can find it in my original question, I have copied the content of my JSON file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76421/discussion-between-manish-and-andris11m).

Answer (score 0):

use this method:

```
 public static <T> T JsonParse(T t, String response)
            throws JsonSyntaxException, IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
        JsonReader reader;
        reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        GsonBuilder b = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = b.create();
        t = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, t.getClass());
        reader.close();
        return t;
    }
```

use this method:

```
ArrayList<Medicine> arrlist=JsonParse(new Medicine(),JsonResponse);
```

i hope its useful to you.

Comment: What does the BooleanSerializer class do?

Comment: sorry..sorry.please remove this...check edited answer

Comment: booleanserializer is to use for when get boolean 0 or 1 instead of true or false in json string.

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly create your classes like this:

```
public class Produse
{
public String Denumire_comerciala;
public List<String > Forme_de_prezentare;
}

public class Dosage
{
public String Nounascuti;
public String Copii;
public String Adulti;
}

public class RootObject
{
public List<String > Substanta_activa;
public List<Produse> Produse;
public Dosage Dozaj;
public List<String > Mentiuni;
public List<String > Cuvinte_cheie;
}
```

2) Then use gson like in this way:

```
Gson _gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
RootObject root= gson.fromJson("*YOUR JSON HERE*", RootObject .class);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: My JSON file contains more objects, not only one, so a single RootObject instance is not enough, is it?

Comment: Did you trie my code? RootObject contains lists objects.

Comment: Yes, I did, and I got an error, because it returns only one RootObject type object, but my file contains more of it, and all of them contains Substanta_activa list, Produse list and so on, so I need a list of RootObject type objects.